# How to add GTIN No for configurable products in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

How to add GTIN no for configurable products in magento. In Simple products I am having gtin number but, how to add that in configurable products.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new product attribute "GTIN". Then assign that attribute to particular attribute set. After that you can set required value of that attribute for particular product.

Comment: Hi,In simple products i am adding like this but in configurable products how we can add

Comment: Same like simple product

Comment: If there is 1 product with 5 colors then in simple product there is 5 different gtin, after adding as configurable product how we will add gtin for this.

Comment: You can add it in associated products(simple) of that main configurable product

Comment: "product in that attribute" This is worded poorly. How do you assign an attribute to all products and have it show in the General tab?